# How to create a symmetric matrix by selecting the symmetric elements that is close to 0

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create a symmetric matrix by selecting the symmetric elements that is close to 0（with less absolute value). For example:

```
#Input:

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   -2    5    2 
[2,]    2   -5    5   -5
[3,]    0   -2   -2    0 
[4,]   -4    9    7   -9 

#Desired Output：

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   -2    0    2 
[2,]   -2   -5   -2   -5 
[3,]    0   -2   -2    0 
[4,]    2   -5    0   -9
```

I tried the following R code, but this code cannot extract the sign information:

```
test_M=matrix(c(1,2,0,-4,-2,-5,-2,9,5,5,-2,7,2,-5,0,-9),nrow=4)
test_M
test_M_final <- pmin(abs(test_M),t(abs(test_M)))
test_M_final
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**. Much simpler, fewer moving parts, and works with 3, 4, 5+ row matrices.

```r
test_M <- matrix(c(1,2,0,-4,-2,-5,-2,9,5), nrow = 3)
test_M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   -4   -2
# [2,]    2   -2    9
# [3,]    0   -5    5
ind <- abs(test_M) > abs(t(test_M))
test_M[ind] <- t(test_M)[ind]
test_M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    0
# [2,]    2   -2   -5
# [3,]    0   -5    5
```

4 rows:

```r
test_M <- matrix(c(1,2,0,-4,-2,-5,-2,9,5,5,-2,7,2,-5,0,-9), nrow = 4)
test_M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   -2    5    2
# [2,]    2   -5    5   -5
# [3,]    0   -2   -2    0
# [4,]   -4    9    7   -9
ind <- abs(test_M) > abs(t(test_M))
test_M[ind] <- t(test_M)[ind]
test_M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   -2    0    2
# [2,]    2   -5   -2   -5
# [3,]    0   -2   -2    0
# [4,]    2   -5    0   -9
```

5 rows:

```r
set.seed(42)
test_M <- matrix(sample(-10:10, size = 25, replace = TRUE), nrow = 5)

test_M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    6    7   -6   -8   -6
# [2,]   -6    6    3   -2    9
# [3,]  -10    4    9   -7   -9
# [4,]   -1   -4    7   -6   -3
# [5,]   -7   -7    4    2   -8
ind <- abs(test_M) > abs(t(test_M))
test_M[ind] <- t(test_M)[ind]
test_M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    6   -6   -6   -1   -6
# [2,]   -6    6    3   -2   -7
# [3,]   -6    3    9   -7    4
# [4,]   -1   -2    7   -6    2
# [5,]   -6   -7    4    2   -8
```

Comment: Hello r2evans: Thanks for your answer, I tried your code, it works for a 3 by 3 matrix. however, it seems it does not work for a 4 by 4 matrix, can you double check for me, thanks!

Comment: Fixed one more time, much better.

Comment: Hello r2evans: Thank you so much for your help. I stuck on this for 2 months, and could not find an answer. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: yes, I followed your previous solution and revised a little bit:test_M=matrix(c(1,2,0,-4,-2,1,-2,9,2,5,-2,7,2,-5,0,-9),nrow=4)
test_M
m2 <- ifelse(abs(test_M[lower.tri(test_M)]) < abs(t(test_M)[lower.tri(t(test_M))]), 
             test_M[lower.tri(test_M)], t(test_M)[lower.tri(t(test_M))])
test_M[lower.tri(test_M)] <- m2
test_M[upper.tri(test_M)] <- t(test_M)[upper.tri(test_M)]
test_M

Comment: Your current solution is much simpler and brilliant, but I found a small flaw: For the 4 by 4 matrix, please check element (1,2) and (2,1)